# Dying Light The Bozak Horde - Weapons are taken during loading screens

Tags: dying-light

For some reason, in Dying Light, the game keeps taking away my items and putting them in the stash. I've done the Bozak Challenges but I haven't beaten it, and every time I go through any loading screen (like when I sleep, move between cities, load a new game or go to a new area) it takes all my things and says that Bozak has taken them and I can retrieve them in my stash.
I've tried everything I can think of, but I'm not able to prevent it.
I even asked the Dying Light page on Facebook why and they still haven't answered after 3 months.
If anyone knows a way around this, please tell me.

I'm currently on The Museum quest in Sector 0, and the part where you come out of the wall where Rais's men with guns are, is freaking impossible.

(And by the way, I've been trying for a month to beat the horde so it would quit happening, but I keep getting stuck on the gas canister level.)

Comment: Lower the difficulty.

Comment: I'm on Normal mode.